# Is there an R function to part data based on a user supplied vector?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
elec.store <- tibble(computer = c(rep("Dell", 3), rep("HP", 3), rep("Lenovo", 3)),
                sold = c(6, 2, 3, 8, 7, 5, 1, 1, 9))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   computer  sold
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 Dell         6
#> 2 Dell         2
#> 3 Dell         3
#> 4 HP           8
#> 5 HP           7
#> 6 HP           5
#> 7 Lenovo       1
#> 8 Lenovo       1
#> 9 Lenovo       9
```

Say I've got my electronics store data frame as shown above. I'd like some type of function that would look something like `parting_function(elec.store, c(2, 6))` that would mutate a new column essentially group my data into arbritrary groups (shown below, in this case I chose alphabet letters, but can be anything). The part is after the 2nd row, and the 6th row, if it is not obvious.

Does such a "parting" function exist, if not how would I write the function? This is what I want it to do, without having to manually select alphabet letters and quantities to repeat (e.g. 2, 4, 3, as shown below):

```
elec.store %>% mutate(grouping = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 3)))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   computer  sold grouping
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 Dell         6 A       
#> 2 Dell         2 A       
#> 3 Dell         3 B       
#> 4 HP           8 B       
#> 5 HP           7 B       
#> 6 HP           5 B       
#> 7 Lenovo       1 C       
#> 8 Lenovo       1 C       
#> 9 Lenovo       9 C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cut` to break rows at defined intervals in `part_vector`.

```
part_vector <- c(2, 6)
elec.store$grouping <- cut(seq_len(nrow(elec.store)),
                        breaks = c(-Inf, part_vector, Inf), 
                        labels = LETTERS[seq_len(length(part_vector) + 1)])



# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  computer  sold grouping
#  <chr>    <dbl> <fct>   
#1 Dell         6 A       
#2 Dell         2 A       
#3 Dell         3 B       
#4 HP           8 B       
#5 HP           7 B       
#6 HP           5 B       
#7 Lenovo       1 C       
#8 Lenovo       1 C       
#9 Lenovo       9 C
```

If you want to fit this in `dplyr` pipes.

```
library(dplyr)
elec.store %>%
  mutate(grouping = cut(seq_len(n()), 
                     breaks = c(-Inf, part_vector, Inf), 
                     labels = LETTERS[seq_len(length(part_vector) + 1)]))
```

---

You could also recreate the same using `findInterval`

```
elec.store$grouping <- LETTERS[findInterval(seq_len(nrow(elec.store)),
                       part_vector, left.open = TRUE) + 1]
```

Comment: what would happen if there's more than 26 "parts"... since there's only 26 letters in the alphabet? Is there any way to account for this you can think of off hand? It probably won't be an issue, but could be useful to at least understand.

Comment: yes, you know what is `length(part_vector)` before hand so you need to supply the `labels` accordingly. Broadly, speaking you should always have `length(part_vector) + 1` labels.

Comment: If you try this you'll see that `elec.store$grouping` entries start turning into "NA" after the "Z" ends the alphabet series. What is the way around this? `library(dplyr); part_vector <- 1:50; tibble(computer = c(rep("Dell", 40), rep("HP", 10), rep("Lenovo", 10)), sold = rnorm(60)) %>%mutate(grouping = cut(seq_len(n()), breaks = c(-Inf, part_vector, Inf), labels = LETTERS[seq_len(length(part_vector) + 1)])) %>% print(n = 60)`

Comment: @JasonHunter You just want something to show different groups based on `part_vector`. `LETTERS` is just a placeholder so limitations of `LETTERS` being only 26 should not matter. Consider using `"A1"`, `"A2"` as labels and do `tibble(computer = c(rep("Dell", 40), rep("HP", 10), rep("Lenovo", 10)), sold = rnorm(60)) %>%
  mutate(grouping = paste0("A", findInterval(seq_len(n()), part_vector)))`. You can have as many labels as you want now.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a grouping index from creating a logical index by comparing with `row_number`, get the cumulative sum, and use that index for changing it to `LETTERS` (inbuilt `vector`)

```
part_vector <- c(2, 6)
elec.store %>% 
    mutate(grouping =  LETTERS[1 + cumsum(row_number() %in% (part_vector + 1))])
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  computer  sold grouping
#  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   
#1 Dell         6 A       
#2 Dell         2 A       
#3 Dell         3 B       
#4 HP           8 B       
#5 HP           7 B       
#6 HP           5 B       
#7 Lenovo       1 C       
#8 Lenovo       1 C       
#9 Lenovo       9 C
```

Here, `LETTERS` is used just for the example.  If we have more groups, it can be easily created

```
grp <- c(LETTERS, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS), 2))))
```

Comment: OK, I think I got it. So the function would look something like `df %>% dplyr::mutate(grouping =  LETTERS[1 + cumsum(row_number() %in% (user_supplied_vector + 1))])` and then the user just enters `df` and `user_supplied_vector`?

Comment: Each time I run the following code things start breaking around rows 600-700 (different each time). The grouping "code" will start repeating (eg AW, AW, AW) or just turns into NA. `library(tidyverse); part_vector <- 1:60000; tibble(computer = c(rep("Dell", 40000), rep("HP", 10000), rep("Lenovo", 10000)), sold = as.integer(rnorm(60000, 100))) %>% mutate(grouping = c(LETTERS, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS), 2))))[1 + cumsum(row_number() %in% (part_vector + 1))]) %>% print(n = 610)`